Include two groups post-test design study for meta-analysis pool?
I am new to meta-analysis and currently trying to find effect of intervention on service users.
Most of the studies that I found were RCTs or quasi-experimental studies with 2 groups pre-post test design. However, a few studies were 2 groups post-test design with no pre-test data available. I would like to know if I can include this post-test design study into the meta-analysis pool? Or simply exclude the post-test design study for meta-analysis? Thanks.

Yes, you can for mean differences but not standardized mean differences. Alternatively, you can calculate the ratio of means which would all pooling of post-treatment scores and change scores.
So, for example, if you are pooling HRQoL that was measured using SF-36 by all the studies then you can pool the reported values (post-treatment scores or change scores). Now if the different study authors report using different scales and there is no uniform scale used by all the studies then you will have group them based on the scale as you should only calculate the mean differences. The Cochrane Handbook has a good explanation on this.
